# How best to unit-test an events abstraction?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, host

I have two questions:

1. How best to unit-test an event listener?
2. Have I properly understood `isHostMethod`?

I'm trying to unit-test an event listener abstraction but the only way I can think to test it is against the window `load` event.

I've a code example here: https://gist.github.com/1502326

Also, I'm using David Mark's (@cinsoft) `isHostMethod` to detect the relevant host object support but was wondering if I had properly understood the concepts or not? So for example, am I right in thinking that a host object/method should be available under the following conditions (although I understand that these 'conditions' are unreliable):

- if `typeof` returns `function` (for majority browsers)
- if `typeof` returns `unknown` (for IE < 9 where its implementation used ActiveX objects for native Functions)
- if `typeof` returns `object` and the value isn't `null` (because ES3 specs have allowed `null` to return `object` which is incorrect behaviour)

If any of these conditions are true then that (again, unreliably) *should* mean that the specified host method is available to use.

But even still the host object/method might be implemented differently to how the specification dictates it should be and so it would be more accurate to do full 'feature detection' where I create the object and see if an event is triggered (or some similar test)?

Thanks for any advice regarding both these enquiries.

Comment: Code cannot exist without context. What you call an abstraction is 3 different functions mapped to the same name depending on the environment. And as you know those alternatives do different things (execution order, `this`, multiple listeners), and they will continue to do so even if you carefully check for their existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a synthetic click event. Given the code in your gist, you could test with:

```
var evt;

events.add( document.body, "click", function() {
    // swap this for an assert(true, "message");
    console.log( true, "supported" );
});

// IE nodes support a click() method
if ( document.body.click ) {
    document.body.click();
} else {
// Standards based events have to be created, initialized and dispatched.    

  evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent( 
      "click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null 
  );

  document.body.dispatchEvent( evt ); 
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/CR4FC/

Tested in: IE6,7,8; Chrome 17; Firefox 10; Safari 5.1.2; Opera 11